# Keep the chat open after changing the page

Tags: php, html

I have a simple PHP website with a homemade Chatbot that interacts with a Node JS application.

How do I keep the Chatbot open when I change the page?

My suggestion was to save the discussion on PHP's session variable and recreating the Chatbot with the stored data, is this the best solution? because on Facebook for example the chat discussion doesn't even disappear.

**EDIT**

Perhaps I didn't make myself quite clear, but it's not just a chatbot website, the chatbot is just a small window (div) opened in the bottom right corner, like any other website with a chatbot extension, example: https://bench.co/blog/ (try changing the page from the nav buttons).

Also, the chatbot is working with a specific SDK, hence sends, receives and stores messages in their own servers.

Comment: you can use websocket

Comment: can you please see my edit, thanks for the reply !

Answer (score 0):

On Facebook chat is not disapperaing, becouse Facebook is not reloading page. You can save data in localstorage and initialite it every time, or use ajax to change content.

Answer (score 0):

you can use websocket with php to avoid reload the page.

Comment: Thanks hamza, can you see my edit please? or do you still think your suggestion is good? I've done some searches on websocket but it has nothing to do with this.

Comment: yeah I see it you have something like Facebook 
and with websocket you will achieve a similar result

Comment: you can check this [example](https://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket/)